# How to get statics on OS X finder folder visits?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Is it possible to know which folders I'm visiting often in the finder app?

I want to put those often-visited folders on the sidebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Smart Folder (which continually updates with the results of a Spotlight search).

Open the target folder (e.g. Documents, your user home, Macintosh HD, etc) in a new folder.
Click on File > New Smart Folder
Click + to add additional criteria.
Set the criteria as Modified within the last 7 days.
Set the `Kind` to `Folder`.

[image]

You can save the Smart Folder in the Sidebar.

This won't give you a 'leader board' of Most Visited Folders, but it will give you some idea of what you've been doing recently.

Comment: Note that depending on what version of OS X / macOS, "Content modified" is not available as an option, use "Last Modified Date" as applicable. As an example, "Content modified" is not available in macOS High Sierra, here one will need to use "Last Modified Date". It appears that "Content modified" was added in macOS Mojave.

Comment: Thank you, another note: while creating the smart folder in Mojave, click on save on the right part of the search bar, then "Add to Sidebar" should be checked.

Answer (score 1):

The default macOS install does not collect statistics on the most visited or most "active" folders in Finder, nor is there an option to enable such data collection.